# Install VirtualBox Extension Pack in VM RHEL 8

Tags: windows, windows-10, virtualbox, virtual-machine, redhat-enterprise-linux

VirtualBox is installed on my Windows 10 operating system. And I installed RHEL8 in VirtualBox. How can I configure VirtualBox's Extension Packs in virtual RHEL 8? Thank you to those who helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a very complete Red Hat article including a section on installing the Guest Extension Pack.

[VBOX guest additions](https://developers.redhat.com/rhel8/install-rhel8-vbox#____________virtualbox_guest_additions_______)

**VirtualBox Guest Additions:**

> Adding VirtualBox Guest Additions to the RHEL VM improves the
> usability in a number of ways:
>
> Enables copy and paste between the host and VM. Eliminates the need
> for the VM to capture the mouse pointer. The integrated mouse pointer
> is much smoother. The VMs screen is dynamically resizable so you can
> have more space to edit. Folders can be easily shared between the host
> and the VM making it easy to share source code. First, make sure
> you’ve installed the latest updates using the instructions above.
> During installation a kernel module will be compiled and installed.
> There are a few prerequisites. First you should have installed
> Development Tools during system installation. If not, use:
>
> $ sudo yum groupinstall "Development Tools" Next, install kernel
> development packages so you can build loadable kernel modules:
>
> $ sudo yum install kernel-devel elfutils-libelf-devel Now insert the
> VirtualBox Guest Additions CD image using the Devices menu entry on
> the VM’s window.  A pop-up will ask you if you want to run the
> software on the CD image. Click Run.
>
> A terminal window will pop-up as the guest additions are built and
> installed.  When complete, hit enter to close the window.
>
> Some of the improvements, such as the mouse pointer integration will
> be immediately available. Others improvements won't be available until
> after the VM is rebooted.